# Max for each group

Tags: sql, oracle

The test of the exercise is:
Considering the conferences with at least 10 editions, for each edition of the conference show the name of the edition and the code of the author who presented the most articles in that edition.
My tables are:

```
Author(CodAuthor, Name, Surname);
Article(CodArticle, Title);
Authors_Article(CodAuthor, CodArticle);
Conference_Editions(Conference, Edition, EditionName);
Author_presents_Article(CodAuthor, Date, Room, CodArticle, Conference, Edition);
```

I wrote the following code:

```
SELECT Apa.CodAuthor, Ec.EdizionName
FROM Conference_Editions Ec JOIN Author_presents_Article Apa ON (Ec.Edition = Apa.Edition) AND (Ec.Conference = Apa.Conference)
WHERE (Apa.Conference In (SELECT Conference
                          FROM Conference_Editions
                          GROUP BY Conference
                          HAVING COUNT(Edition)>10))
GROUP BY Apa.Conference, Apa.Edition, Apa.CodAuthor, Ec.EdizionName;
```

But I don't know how to find the author who presented the most articles for each edition.

Comment: for most articles, you can use `having` with `max(count(edition))`

Comment: I can't understand your suggestion, if at the end of the code I just add `HAVING MAX(COUNT(edition))`, it gaves me the following error: group function is nested too deeply.

Comment: a analytic function such as `select..., count(*) over (partition by CODAuthor, CodArticle, Conference, Edition) as ArtCountAtconfEd` would give you the count of articles by author for each conference edition.  from it you could max by the conference/edition.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
SELECT Apa.CodAuthor, Ec.EdizionName
FROM Conference_Editions Ec JOIN Author_presents_Article Apa ON (Ec.Edition = Apa.Edition) AND (Ec.Conference = Apa.Conference)
WHERE (Apa.Conference In (SELECT Conference
                          FROM Conference_Editions
                          GROUP BY Conference
                          HAVING COUNT(Edition)>=10))
GROUP BY Apa.Conference, Apa.Edition, Apa.CodAuthor, Ec.EdizionName
HAVING COUNT(*)=(SELECT MAX(Counter)
                 FROM (SELECT Conference, Edition, AuthorCode, COUNT(*) AS Counter
                       FROM Author_presents_Article
                       GROUP BY Conference, Edition, AuthorCode) AS Counting
                 WHERE Apa.Conference=Counting.Conference AND Apa.Edition=Counting.Edition);
```

Comment: I think It returns just one record (the author who has presented the most articles in general) not an author for each edition, but maybe I'm wrong